# Show two fragments out of three, when button pressed push the first fragment to the left and bring the third in to the screen

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, fragment

I got a problem with fragments and the layout. 
I have 3 fragments. SearchFragment, ResultFragment and DetailedFragment.
So far I've got the SearchFragment and ResultFragment showing up nicely in landscape-mode.

I can't seem to figure out or find a way to when someone clicks the search button, the search fragment should not longer be shown, instead ResultFragment should take that place and on the right side DetailedFragment should take ResultFragments place.

I do have 2 different Layouts. One is the acitivty_main, wich works well.
and I got another layout with ResultFragment and DetailedView, is there anyway to swap the activity_main.xml to the other xml?

|Search|Result| -> |Result|Detailed|

Comment: post your layout, post your code.

Comment: you can use viewpager

Comment: @BirajZalavadia answered 1 second before you :D

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into viewPager. It can help you acheive exactly what you are asking for. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html